# Send email by javascript using custom SMTP

Tags: javascript, cordova, email, smtp

i am curious if there is any possibility to send email just by JS (i am supposed to make phonegap app). I imagine something like connecting to specified SMTP server with login and pass, and then send mails using the smtp connection.
I have made php code, that i can just post the mail to and it gets the work done, but i am not sure if my teacher would accept this solution. I would just want it to work like the native android email client.
Is there any possibility, or any source of relevant information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to send SMTP via client-side javascript, but you can use services such as [SendGrid](http://SendGrid.com) which allows you to send emails via a REST API. Most applications are going to have the phone app make a call to a back-end server to send out the SMTP message (such as your PHP code). Since you are using PhoneGap, you could just make an AJAX call to a PHP file and send the information to then pass to the SMTP server if you don't want to use an outside service.

Comment: Alright then, i will just stick with the php solution.